# using CASE in T-SQL in the where clause?

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

Im trying to use case to vary the value im checking in a where clause but I'm getting the error:

incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

SQL Server 2005

```
select * 
from   table
where  ((CASE when adsl_order_id like '95037%'
         then select '000000'+substring(adsl_order_id,6,6)
         ELSE select adsl_order_id
       END)
       not in (select mwebID from tmp_csv_dawis_bruger0105)
```

Answer (score 45):

Here is one way to include a case statement in a Where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN somecondition THEN 1 
    WHEN someothercondition THEN 2
    ELSE ... END
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (SELECT CASE WHEN adsl_order_id LIKE '95037%'
              THEN '000000' + SUBSTRING(adsl_order_id, 6, 6)
              ELSE adsl_order_id
              END)
      NOT IN (select mwebID from tmp_csv_dawis_bruger0105)
```

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is one possibility:

```
select * 
from mytable
where not exists (
    select * 
    from 
        tmp_csv_dawis_bruger0105
    where 
        mwebID = 
        CASE when mytable.adsl_order_id like '95037%' then '000000' + substring(mytable.adsl_order_id,6,6)
        ELSE mytable.adsl_order_id END
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question looking for an answer thinking WHERE CASE ... would be the solution. I could not adapt the answers to my problem, but this technique to use a parameter that could be null, partial, or specific, works:

```
CREATE PROC myproc  @vJobID VARCHAR (11) 
AS
SELECT * FROM Jobs 

WHERE Jobs.JobID like coalesce(@vJobID+'%','%')
```

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You have one too many opening parentheses before the CASE expression.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in the SELECT clause...

```
select *, (CASE when adsl_order_id like '95037%'
         then '000000'+substring(adsl_order_id,6,6)
         ELSE adsl_order_id
       END) AS Id
from   table
where  not in (select mwebID from tmp_csv_dawis_bruger0105)
```

Also, you don't need to "SELECT" the result of the CASE.