# How to develop TSQL Case Where statement

Tags: t-sql, case, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using CASE in T-SQL in the where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006242/using-case-in-t-sql-in-the-where-clause)
>   [How to best add a report parameter with multiple values to multiple reports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411326/how-to-best-add-a-report-parameter-with-multiple-values-to-multiple-reports)

I am using SSMS 2008 R2 to develop a query that will return records as follows.
I have one parameter for this dataset that can either be one value or multiple values.  But the tricky part is that both the single value and multiple values are part of the same list:
A = multi-value
B, C, D = single values

So if A is selected, A includes all 3 values: B, C, D.
But if B is selected, only B records should show.

What is the best way to handle this within my sproc?
So far I created a permanent table which stores the info for B,C,D.  And now I'm trying to figure out how to JOIN in B,C,D if A is selected.  Should I use a CASE statement in my WHERE clause?  Some special kind of JOIN?  A CTE?

Comment: Posting some sample data, your table structure, expected results and what you have tried would be very helpful.  Your word problem is not that easy to decipher.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006242/using-case-in-t-sql-in-the-where-clause